# Phoenix server does not start - module Plug.Cowboy is not available

Tags: phoenix-framework

I am new to phoenix and elixir. I am creating a phoenix web server as backend API server. I have followed steps given on phoenix framework website.

Software version:

> Erlang/OTP 21 [erts-10.2.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]
>
> Elixir 1.8.1 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 20)
>
> Phoenix v1.4.0-dev

and deps

```
  {:phoenix, github: "phoenixframework/phoenix", override: true},
  {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.0"},
  {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.2"},
  {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
  {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.11"},
  {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},
  {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
  {:jason, "~> 1.0"},
  {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"}
```

When I am trying to run `mix phx.server`, I am getting following errors:

```
[info] Application hello exited: Hello.Application.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: HelloWeb.Endpoint
    ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
        ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Plug.Cowboy.child_spec/1 is undefined (module Plug.Cowboy is not available)
            Plug.Cowboy.child_spec([scheme: :http, plug: {HelloWeb.Endpoint, []}, options: [dispatch: [_: [{"/phoenix/live_reload/socket/websocket", Phoenix.Endpoint.CowboyWebSocket, {Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket, {HelloWeb.Endpoint, Phoenix.LiveReloader.Socket, [path: "/websocket", serializer: [{Phoenix.Socket.V1.JSONSerializer, "~> 1.0.0"}, {Phoenix.Socket.V2.JSONSerializer, "~> 2.0.0"}], timeout: 60000, transport_log: false, compress: false]}}}, {"/socket/websocket", Phoenix.Endpoint.CowboyWebSocket, {Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket, {HelloWeb.Endpoint, HelloWeb.UserSocket, [path: "/websocket", serializer: [{Phoenix.Socket.V1.JSONSerializer, "~> 1.0.0"}, {Phoenix.Socket.V2.JSONSerializer, "~> 2.0.0"}], timeout: 60000, transport_log: false, compress: false]}}}, {:_, Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler, {HelloWeb.Endpoint, []}}]], port: 4000, otp_app: :hello]])
            (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/cowboy_adapter.ex:96: Phoenix.Endpoint.CowboyAdapter.child_spec/3
            (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/supervisor.ex:108: anonymous fn/6 in Phoenix.Endpoint.Supervisor.server_children/4
            (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1940: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
            (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/supervisor.ex:99: Phoenix.Endpoint.Supervisor.server_children/4
            (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/supervisor.ex:59: Phoenix.Endpoint.Supervisor.init/1
            (stdlib) supervisor.erl:295: :supervisor.init/1
            (stdlib) gen_server.erl:374: :gen_server.init_it/2
            (stdlib) gen_server.erl:342: :gen_server.init_it/6
            (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

I tried changing version of cowboy to 2.6.3 (that seems latest as per brew), but still getting the same error.

Please help me solve this.

-Thanks,
Shaila

Comment: have you run `mix deps.get`?

Comment: Yes. I ran mix deps.get. But still getting the same error.

Comment: Worked after i reinstalled phoenix with version 1.4.0. This gave new deps as

      {:phoenix, "~> 1.4.0"},
      {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.1"},
      {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 4.0"},
      {:ecto_sql, "~> 3.0"},
      {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
      {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.11"},
      {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.2", only: :dev},
      {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
      {:jason, "~> 1.0"},
      {:plug_cowboy, "~> 2.0"}            
   
  cowboy got replaced with plug_cowboy.

Comment: @Shaila123456789, Go ahead and post your comment as an answer.  In a couple of days, the forum software will allow you to give your answer a checkmark and close the topic.

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same issue while updating a old project. apparently Chris Mccord put phoenix update guides in his gist account. you can find all from here: https://gist.github.com/chrismccord

so if you are updating from 1.3 to 1.4 you have to replace the cowboy dependency to plug_cowboy.

[image]

detailed instructions are available at here: https://gist.github.com/chrismccord/bb1f8b136f5a9e4abc0bfc07b832257e